# Ensure that all classes will share same method and fields

Tags: c#, .net

I my data access layer I want to use DTOs and make sure that all gateways (table data gateway) will implement method which return List of some DTO specific for given gateway. 
To make this happen I have created **empty** interface like this

```
public interface IDataTransferObject{}
```

implemented this interface by all DTOs like this

```
public class UserAccountTypeDTO : IDataTransferObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int AccountTitle { get; set; }
    public int CreditTypeId { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
}
```

then I have made generic interface for all my gateways

```
public interface IDefaultGateway<D> where D:IDataTransferObject
{
    List<D> Read(SqlDataReader sqlReader);
}
```

and finally implemented IDefaultGateway by my gateways

```
class UserAccountTypeGW : IDefaultGateway<UserAccountTypeDTO>
{
    private const string Table = " UserAccountType ";

    private string SelectAll = "select * from" + Table + "";
    private string SelectById = ...;


    public List<UserAccountTypeDTO> Read(SqlDataReader sqlReader)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Is it ok to make empty interfaces just to somehow group classes together even if they don't share any behavior?

Fields in gateways are the same only its values are changing. I did copy and paste for fields to each gateway and I would like to know whether there is faster/lazier way how to do this.

- Interface and fields are not friends, therefore it could have been defined as properties. Since there is a need to create constructor in each DTO to initialize properties and also make set private it turns out to be little bit worse than what I did.
- Abstract class was pretty much the same as interface
- Create base class, define fields and methods and initialize (or override) them in gateway constructor is better in this case or pretty much the same as what have I done?

Comment: Why do all classes need to shared the same methods and fields? What code would use `IDataTransferObject` or `IDefaultGateway<D>`? It seems like they only exist to remind the programmer to follow a particular pattern in the code, but that no one would actually use them via the interfaces or base classes you are describing.

Comment: Yes they are there just as to remind me not to forget that method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word you need to search for is called `Marker Interfaces`. This is the guideline from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229022%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> AVOID using marker interfaces (interfaces with no members).
>   If you need to mark a class as having a specific characteristic (marker), in general, use a custom attribute rather than an interface.

Having said that, it is easier to check if a class implements an interface than to check if it has an attribute.

And as @Groo has mentioned in the comment section of this answer, which is a really good point:

> Marker interfaces also at least give some compile-time checks, compared to attribute

Comment: Marker interfaces also at least give some compile-time checks, compared to attributes.

Comment: So it is trade off between correctness and convenience. Thank you very much. I found both comments about abstract classes useful but I mark this as a correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the second part of the question (how to avoid code duplication), this is what abstract classes are for.

You can provide some default values which derived classes can override if needed:

```
abstract class BaseGateway<T> : IDefaultGateway<T> where T : IDataTransferObject
{
    readonly string _tableName;
    readonly string _selectAll;

    public BaseGateway()
    {
        // default table name
        _tableName = this.GetType().Name.Replace("DTO", "");
        _selectAll = $"select * from {_tableName}";
    }

    // these members are virtual, so that they can be overriden
    protected virtual string TableName => _tableName;
    protected virtual string SelectAll => _selectAll;

    // derived classes should implement their own 'Read' method
    public abstract List<T> Read(IDataReader sqlReader);
}
```

However, note that doing stuff like this makes your code prone to SQL injection attacks. It would be a better idea to use an ORM, or at least a "micro" ORM like [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper).

Dapper gives you this simplicity in a couple of plain `IDbConnection` extension methods:

```
public class Dog
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}            

using (IDbConnection conn = OpenConnection())
{
    var dog = conn
        .Query<Dog>("Select * from Dog where Age = @Age", new { Age = 10 })
        .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: Thank you this looks good. May I ask you when/how can sql injection can be used? I don't say it is not possible, but I am not familiar with this problematic and I do not understand how it could be possible to catch sql command I send to db and change it. 

I use SqlCommand and its property Parameters to set up where clause params. I have heard it should take care of dangerous inputs.

Comment: @Bendom: oh, no problem then, I just wanted to make sure you and other readers were aware of it since it seemed you would be building lots of sql strings yourself. Parameterized queries prevent injection, while Dapper also automatically populates classes with returned data, and is [very fast in doing so](https://www.exceptionnotfound.net/dapper-vs-entity-framework-vs-ado-net-performance-benchmarking/).

Answer (score 1):

Avoid using those marker interfaces. The only 'good' reason to use marker interfaces nowadays is if you plan to manipulate certain types of objects using reflection (and it's not a case this time).

In this case - abstract class seems to be the best choice. Define that `Read()` method inside the abstract class and properties with their default implementation. Override it with `virtual` method in all the descendants as needed. This way you  won't even need a wrapper class for reading every specific type of object, as you will be able to reference that object and call `Read()` on it directly.